# Ktor Server Responds with 406 Error in Postman

Tags: postman, ktor

I am doing a backend server and I am having some trouble while testing /register route.
I think that I have configured everything correctly but it gives me the 406 error when I try to do a POST method on Postman this is the link that I am using ´http://127.0.0.1:8080/v1/users/register´
This i connected to a PostGreSQL DB, after I do the request on Postman I even checked the database, but there is nothing there, before this routing part I already have created a table using Ktor.

This is my route file

```
fun Route.userRoutes(db: repo, jwtService: JwtService, hashFunction: (String) -> String) {
    route("/v1/users") {
        post("/register") {
            try {
                val registerRequest = call.receive<RegisterRequest>()

                // Handle registration logic
                val user = User(registerRequest.email, hashFunction(registerRequest.password), registerRequest.name)
                db.addUser(user)
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, SimpleResponse(true, jwtService.generateToken(user)))

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // Handle registration errors
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, SimpleResponse(false, "Missing Some Fields or Registration Failed"))
            }
        }
```

Register class

```
data class RegisterRequest(
    val email:String,
    val name:String,
    val password:String
)
```

SimpleResponse class

```
package com.example.data.model

data class SimpleResponse(
    val success:Boolean,
    val message:String
)
```

And when I try to send the POST on POSTMAN this is what appears on my console in IntelliJ

```
2023-12-29 21:42:28.514 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.server.routing.Routing - Trace for [v1, users, register]
/, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
  /session, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /session
  /json, segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /json
  /, segment:0 -> SUCCESS @ /
    /(method:GET), segment:0 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /(method:GET)
  /v1, segment:1 -> SUCCESS @ /v1
    /v1/users, segment:2 -> SUCCESS @ /v1/users
      /v1/users/register, segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /v1/users/register
        /v1/users/register/(method:POST), segment:3 -> SUCCESS @ /v1/users/register/(method:POST)
      /v1/users/login, segment:2 -> FAILURE "Selector didn't match" @ /v1/users/login
Matched routes:
  "" -> "v1" -> "users" -> "register" -> "(method:POST)"
Route resolve result:
  SUCCESS @ /v1/users/register/(method:POST)
2023-12-30 21:04:26.349 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.server.engine.DefaultTransform - No Default Transformations found for class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel and expected type TypeInfo(type=class com.example.data.model.RegisterRequest, reifiedType=class com.example.data.model.RegisterRequest, kotlinType=com.example.data.model.RegisterRequest) for call /v1/users/register
2023-12-30 21:04:26.375 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - No suitable content converter found for request type class com.example.data.model.RegisterRequest
2023-12-30 21:04:26.384 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE io.ktor.server.sessions.Sessions - Sending session data for /v1/users/register: MY_SESSION
2023-12-30 21:04:26.407 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE i.k.s.p.c.ContentNegotiation - No suitable content converter found for response type class com.example.data.model.SimpleResponse and body SimpleResponse(success=false, message=Missing Some Fields)
```

the body on the request is this

```
{
    "name": "john",
    "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
    "password": "pass"
}
```

```
fun Application.configureSerialization() {

    install(ContentNegotiation) {

            Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                encodeDefaults = false
            }

    }

    routing {
        get("/json/gson") {
            call.respond(mapOf("hello" to "world"))
        }
    }
}
```

I have checked the headers  tab on Postman and I have the Content-Type application/json and also the Accept "/"

The dependencies on Gradle I used latest.release

This is just for a simple Note App for android.

The problem seems to be because the RegisterRequest and SimpleResponse I think.

This is my first time using Ktor so sorry if I'm a bit behind in some aspects. Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you please try to remove all irrelevant to the problem code and post your findings here?

Answer (score 0):

Just annotate all your data classes with @serializable
It'll work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).